Bluetooth Deathloop. Mouse is disconnecting every 20 seconds and wants to pair
after several attempts to connect my Bluetooth mouse with Ubuntu I have to admit defeat.
I have a Logi 240 Bluetooth mouse without adapter. So it connects directly to the laptop.  I have tried it with Ubuntu LTS 20.24 and with the new version of Ubuntu Budgie but nothing has worked.
Here is the problem.
If I somehow manage to connect the mouse, the connection is interrupted after about 20-30 seconds and I get a message that I have to pair it. So I pair it and it works again. But again for 20-30 seconds. If I hold the mouse still, nothing happens! The Mouse is just disconnecting. But when I move it, the pair message appears again. I am trapped in a loop
I have fiddled with bluez, blueman, bluetoothctl, main.conf and autosuspends and what else is in the forums but nothing has helped.
I hope someone can help me

I have different, but maybe related, behaviour.  When I dual boot from Linux to Windows and back again, it still shows as a paired M240 but does not connect, and when I do reconnect I see the "Address" has changed slightly e.g. ""D4:95:37:C1:8C:2B" when previously it was "D4:95:37:C1:8C:2A". I suspect the mouse changes its Address when you hold the "pair" button underneath it, and it going into pairing mode.  So, for you, when you go to Bluetooth settings and select the M240 does the Address you see change each time it connects?
